# Set UIDatepicker programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

I have a datepicker and 2 buttons. And I want to set the datepicker value programmatically when I click the button. Like when I press the first button the datepicker value becomes today's date and 00:00:00: time and when I press the second button the datepicker value becomes today's date and 23:59:59 time.

How to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple task, assuming that you already added two functions beging invoked on button pressing you need something like this:

```
-(IBAction)beginPressed:(id)sender
{
  NSDate * now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents * comps = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
  [comps setHour:0];
  [comps setMinute:0];
  [comps setSecond:0];
  NSDate * date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
  [self.datePicker setDate:date animated:TRUE];

}
-(IBAction)endPressed:(id)sender
{
  NSDate * now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents * comps = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
  [comps setHour:23];
  [comps setMinute:59];
  [comps setSecond:59];
  NSDate * date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
  [self.datePicker setDate:date animated:TRUE];
}
```

I think the part with setting the components wasn't clear to you, check the API of the above classes and you will find more.

**Edit**: I changed the calendar to the current default calendar and initialized the calendar with now.

Comment: Thanks @iOS, but it didn't give the wanted result. it gave January 1 0001. where i need it to be today's date such as October 28 2012 00:00:00 and the other to be October 28 2012 23:59:59

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
  dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
  NSDate *exampleDateFromString =[dateFormat dateFromString:@"8:48 AM"]; 
  date-picker.minimumDate=exampleDateFromString;
 [date-picker setDate:exampleDateFromString];
```

Comment: This works very well for a datePicker set to setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering how to do this in Swift:

```
let now = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let comp = cal.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: now)
comp.hour = 0 // or whatever you need
comp.minute = 0
let date = cal.dateFromComponents(comp)!
picker.setDate(date, animated: true)
```